# kibana development environment is too slow

Tags: webpack, kibana

I use `bin/kibana.bat --dev` to run kibana server

When there is a changing on src code, webpack will monitor and pack src code to 
bundle.js

The procedure can be very very long and usually the browser will crash somehow.

It will cost almost five minutes when I do a very small change on even .css file and refresh to see the result.

How can I speed up the bundle speed on dev envionment ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
optimize.unsafeCache: false
```

To your kibana.yml
That will disable the webpack optimizaton

Comment: Thanks.I have tried this method.It seems that the loading time is shortened to less than 1 minutes when source code changing,but still Chrome browser often  crashed.However firefox worked fine.